# Where to put faulty RAM?

Tags: linux, memory, dual-channel

I have dual channel motherboard and two pairs of memory cards of which one of other pair is a bit faulty, one bit or something. I found out that I can disable Linux from using the bad RAM addresses, but does dual channel still work, as those two cards are not identical due to other one being faulty?

Does it matter in which slot I put the faulty RAM card? I mean if I e.g. want to boot something from USB, the software does not know about the faulty RAM, and I want to minimize the possibility of that using those faulty addresses.

Comment: While your OS may be able to avoid the faulty RAM, your hardware probably cannot. Using faulty RAM should never be considered an ongoing or regular state, and OS-avoidance should only be utilized to keep a critical system running long enough to replace the faulty modules.

Comment: If memory is truly faulty (hardware error) I put it in the recycle bin.

Comment: The best slot for faulty RAM is the small round slot beside your desk. It gets emptied regularly. You'll then have space inside your PC for good RAM.

Comment: @Mokubai is that slot compatible with all types of RAM :D

Comment: @Mokubai, Excellent! It implements garbage collection *far* more reliably than Java or C# do, causes lower power consumption and gives new meaning to Windows' Recycle Bin. Another use: remove epoxy with piranha etch (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piranha_solution -- **Caution**) and examine awesome silicon circuitry under an electron microscope.

Comment: @Mokubai you must not put electric waste in trash bin, but recycle it. That is the way in Finland, at least.

Comment: @music2myear What do you mean by that the hardware cannot avoid the faulty RAM?

Comment: You said the OS has a way to identify and avoid bad RAM addresses, but your BIOS/UEFI and system hardware do not, so anything outside the Linux OS risks touching those  bad addresses and generating faults.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have 4 memory sticks of which you believe one is bad.
Have you confirmed it is actually the stick thats bad - i.e. by moving them around to ensure it's not a problem with one of the slots on the motherboard?

If you are sure it's the stick, as others have stated there is no point putting a bad stick in the computer, in a pinch it might be possible to put the three good sticks into three different banks, so that all of them are single channel - that may allow you to boot and use the full capacity of the 3 good sticks however they will all be single channel, so I am not sure the extra RAM is worth the performance penalty.

Typically you should run a matched pair in a bank, so I would recommend buying two new RAM sticks - that will leave you with a spare, which you can keep in the draw incase one of the other two sticks go bad in future.

Comment: Yes, I have four smaller capacity cards with which memtest86+ passes tests without an error.

Comment: Even with the good ones I have a selection between 12GB single channel and 8GB dual channel.